# Splitting time by the hour Python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 like this, where starttime and endtime are datetime objects.

StartTime   EndTime

9:08      9:10
9:10      9:35
9:35      9:55
9:55      10:10
10:10     10:20

If endtime.hour is not the same as startime.hour, I would like to split times like this

StartTime   EndTime

9:08          9:10

9:10          9:55

**9:55          10:00**

**10:00         10:10**

10:10         10:20

Essentially insert a row into the existing dataframe df1. I have looked at a ton of examples but haven't figured out how to do this. If my question isn't clear please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: which part(s) are you stuck on? converting to datetime and extracting the hour, or inserting a row into a dataframe? I think you're going to want to write a helper function or two, and you may have to reset the index.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want ...

```
# load your data into a DataFrame
data="""StartTime EndTime
9:08 9:10
9:10 9:35
9:35 9:55
9:55 10:10
10:10 10:20
"""
from StringIO import StringIO # import from io for Python 3
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=0, sep=' ', index_col=None)

# convert strings to Pandas Timestamps (we will ignore the date bit) ...
import datetime as dt
df.StartTime = [dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M') for x in df.StartTime]
df.EndTime = [dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M') for x in df.EndTime]

# assumption - all intervals are less than 60 minutes
#            - ie. no multi-hour intervals

# add rows
dfa = df[df.StartTime.dt.hour != df.EndTime.dt.hour].copy()
dfa.EndTime = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), '%H') for x in dfa.EndTime.dt.hour]

# play with the start hour ...
df.StartTime = df.StartTime.where(df.StartTime.dt.hour == df.EndTime.dt.hour,
    other = [dt.datetime.strptime(str(x), '%H') for x in df.EndTime.dt.hour])

# bring back together and sort
df = pd.concat([df, dfa], axis=0) #top/bottom
df = df.sort('StartTime')

# convert the Timestamps to times for easy reading
df.StartTime = [x.time() for x in df.StartTime]
df.EndTime = [x.time() for x in df.EndTime]
```

And yields

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
  StartTime   EndTime
0  09:08:00  09:10:00
1  09:10:00  09:35:00
2  09:35:00  09:55:00
3  09:55:00  10:00:00
3  10:00:00  10:10:00
4  10:10:00  10:20:00
```